# Remove text using str_Replace

Tags: php, html

I have seven lines of text. I want to use PHP to do the things below.

First of all, I want to remove all the lines which don't have the word 'MARCO1998' in them.

Then, for the remaining lines, I want to remove everything except for the 1-3 numbers **after** the word 'MAP'

And then, after there's only seven rows of 1-3 numbers left, I want to remove the duplicates.

```
17.10.16    11:32:39    MAP104  MARCO1998   zerstoert   NIGHTRIDER
17.10.16    14:17:25    MAP66   MARCO1998   zerstoert   SPARTACULS
17.10.16    14:26:15    MAP66   MARCO1998   zerstoert   SUPERONE
17.10.16    23:09:04    MAP104  MARCO1998   zerstoert   JOCKSTRAP7
18.10.16    14:27:45    MAP244  MARCO1998   zerstoert   MARIA07
18.10.16    19:50:37    MAP40   MARCO1998   zerstoert   LILIENKILL
19.10.16    07:08:41    MAP186  KOBOLD1 zerstoert   MARCO1998
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service where other people write complete code solutions for you. Show us what you have tried so far and at what point you are stuck and you might get an answer.

Comment: So, could you share the code you already tried?

Comment: @RicardoPontual I already have an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// Input string with newlines
$str = "17.10.16    11:32:39    MAP104  MARCO1998   zerstoert   NIGHTRIDER
17.10.16    14:17:25    MAP66   MARCO1998   zerstoert   SPARTACULS
17.10.16    14:26:15    MAP66   MARCO1998   zerstoert   SUPERONE
17.10.16    23:09:04    MAP104  MARCO1998   zerstoert   JOCKSTRAP7
18.10.16    14:27:45    MAP244  MARCO1998   zerstoert   MARIA07
18.10.16    19:50:37    MAP40   MARCO1998   zerstoert   LILIENKILL
19.10.16    07:08:41    MAP186  KOBOLD1 zerstoert   MARCO1998";

// Split long string on newlines
$str_split = explode("\n", $str);
$values = [];

// Loop each line
foreach ($str_split as $v) {
    // If the line does not contain MARCO1998, we skip this line
    if (strpos($v, 'MARCO1998') === false) {
        continue;
    }

    // Use regex to capture MAP<integer>{1,3}
    preg_match_all('/MAP(?P<id>[0-9]{1,3})/', $v, $matches);

    // Make sure that the match returned a valid result
    if (isset($matches['id']) and isset($matches['id'][0]) and strlen($matches['id'][0]) > 0) {
        $values[] = $matches['id'][0];
    }
}

print_r($values); //  104, 66, 66, 104, 244, 40, 186

// If you only like to have the unique values
$values = array_unique($values);
print_r($values); // 104, 66, 244, 40, 186

// Output each ID
foreach ($values as $v) {
    echo $v;
}
```

Comment: Hello, does this remove the duplicated values? Sorry, I added it to my post a bit late.

Comment: @baloonrocket I've edited my answer to filter out duplicates. Hope this solves your problem. Please accept answer if it does.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more thing. I tried using the `implode` function but it didn't work.... I need to display each result under the previous one, not in an array. Thanks for your help so far. I will accept your answer and how can I give you reputation?

Comment: @baloonrocket I've added a loop at the end of the code. This will output all the IDs. If you'd like space between them you might need to change the line `echo $v;` to `echo $v . '<br />';`. Accepting the answer and/or voting my answer up gives me rep.